# How to count things within string in Python

Tags: python, string, count

I have data where one column is a string. This column contains text, such as:

| # | financial_covenants |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Value is 6.00 |
| 2. | Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Decreasing from 4.00 to 3.00, Min. Fixed Charge Coverage Ratio: Value is 1.20 |
| 3 | Min. Interest Coverage Ratio: Value is 3.00 |
| 4 | Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Decreasing from 4.00 to 3.50, Min. Interest Coverage Ratio: Value is 3.00 |
| 5 | Max. Leverage Ratio: Value is 0.6, Tangible Net Worth: 7.88e+008, Min. Fixed Charge Coverage Ratio: Value is 1.75, Min. Debt Service Coverage Ratio: Value is 2.00 |

I want a new column that counts how many covenants there are in "financial_covenants".
As you can see, the covenants are divided by a comma.
I want my final result to look like this:

| financial_covenants | num_of_cov |
| --- | --- |
| Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Value is 6.00 | 1 |
| Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Decreasing from 4.00 to 3.00, Min. Fixed Charge Coverage Ratio: Value is 1.20 | 2 |
| Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Value is 3.00 | 1 |
| Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Decreasing from 4.00 to 3.50, Min. Interest Coverage Ratio: Value is 3.00 | 2 |
| Max. Leverage Ratio: Value is 0.6, Tangible Net Worth: 7.88e+008, Min. Fixed Charge Coverage Ratio: Value is 1.75, Min. Debt Service Coverage Ratio: Value is 2.00 | 4 |

The data set is large (3000 rows), and these phrases differ among themselves in values, such like:
Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Value is **3.00** and Max. Debt to Cash Flow: Value is **6.00**. I am not interested in these values, but just want to know how many covenants there are.

Do you have any idea how to do this in Python?

Comment: could you post your code? You mention columns. Does it mean you are using pandas and have your data as a Dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the assumption that your data is in a pandas DataFrame called df with columns as labelled then you could use:

```
df['num_of_cov'] = df['financial_covenants'].map(lambda row : len(row.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks to me that you could use:

```
counts = [] # structure to store the results

for financial_covenant in financial_covenants: # your structure containing rows

    parts = financial_covenant.split(',') # this will split your sentence using commas as delimiters

    count = len(parts) # this will count the number of parts obtained

    counts.append(count) # this will store the final results in a array

print(counts) # displays [1, 2, 1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Looks like a useful solution, and while the workings of the code should be self-explanatory to experienced programmers (who probably wouldn't be asking the original question),  it might be helpful to add additional in-code comments or external explanation about what is going on for inexperienced programmers.

Comment: Fair enough, updated. Cheers